# PHP - Struggling with sessions

Tags: php, session, blackjack

I am trying to make a php blackjack game, but i am struggling to use sessions. My goal is to randomly pick 2 cards and display them on the screen with an image of the card picked. i can get one card on screen but i cant figure out how to display the second at the same time and then if needed to display a third. I will post what code i already have. Any help much appreciated.

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    $suits = array('Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts' ,'Spades');
    $cards = array('2' => 2, '3' => 3, '4' => 4, '5 '=> 5, '6' => 6, '7' => 7, '8' => 8, '9' => 9, '10' => 10, 'Jack' => 10, 'Queen' => 10 ,'King' => 10 ,'Ace '=> 11);

     $hand = array();

    $cardNum = rand(1, 52);

    $theCard = $cards [$cardNum % 13];

    $theTrump = $suits[floor ($cardNum / 13)];

    echo '<br> the card selected was ' . $theCard . ' of '. $theTrump;

    echo '<img src= '. $theCard .'_of_'. $theTrump  . '.png >';

    array_push($hand,  "$theCard");

   print_r($hand);

   $_SESSION[card]=$cards;

    foreach ($_SESSION[card] as $key=> $value) {
     echo 'Total score is'.$value.':';
      }



     ?>

    <form>
      <input type="button" onclick="history.go(0)" value="Hit">
    </form>
```

Comment: you have a few errors in your code, I am not sure what you are trying to do with $_SESSION, but I don't think your concept of $_SESSION is correct yet. To get you pointed in the right direction, start by making a $deck variable consisting of 52 cards at some point before $cardNum is picked and used.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, how would i go about that just start typing out the cards or? Sorry for the stupid question im very new to this